# How to find by composite object property?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to find all plans where city name equal Madrin(for example).
But i always get an error.

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: location.lName of: io.onek.entity.FuturePlan.

Help me figure out it.

FuturePlan

```
@Entity
public class FuturePlan {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int fpId;
private String about;
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-mm-yyyy")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date travelDate;
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private User user;
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Location location;

public FuturePlan() {
    super();
}

public FuturePlan(String about, Date travelDate) {
    super();
    this.about = about;
    this.travelDate = travelDate;
}

public FuturePlan(String about, Date travelDate, User user, Location location) {
    this.about = about;
    this.travelDate = travelDate;
    this.user = user;
    this.location = location;
}
..get/set/
```

Location

```
@Entity
public class Location {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int lId;
private String lName;

public Location() {
    super();
}

public Location(int lId, String lName) {
    super();
    this.lId = lId;
    this.lName = lName;
}
```

Method from my DAOImpl.

```
@Override
public List<FuturePlan> findByLocation(String name) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(FuturePlan.class);
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("location.lName", name));
    List<FuturePlan> list =  cr.list();
    session.close();
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a join:

```
cr.createAlias("location", "l"));
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("l.lName", name));
```

But I would really avoid using Criteria for such a simple static query. Use JPQL:

```
select fp from FuturePlan fp where fp.location.lName = :name
```

Comment: `HQL` — because of he uses `Session`. And this `HQL` produces a `cross join`.